# How to stop hacking in-app purchases in android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've implemented in-app purchases in my android game and did all verification steps available out there like sending receipts to server with token/developer payload etc for authentication purpose and every thing is working fine. However, I discovered some of the users are sharing in-apps by giving their account details. Here is my understanding,

In my game, I use google play games services (GPG) to get unique user id and when you purchase any in-apps, I link that purchase with your id and send to server for authentication. But here is the issue, GPG account and google play store account could be different. In that case, when I restore all non-consumables inapps, I send them to our server for authentication and then link them with the current logged in GPG account. In this way, users are taking other users GPG account and login the game so all purchases get restored and assign to the new GPG account.

Is there anyway I can get playstore account details through inapp receipt to know who is the genuine buyer of it?

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: You should be associating the InApp purchases with a google account. Look into how games like Clash of Clans and many others handle the InApp purchases.

Comment: Can you explain bit more? You mean associate purchases with play store account? If yes, then it would solve the issue but the problem is I can't get any information regarding playstore account

Comment: May be you can have a google sign in button to allow user to save his profile and purchases there. Internally of course you will be using GPG but  by this way you will have it associated with a google account as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, but perhaps the best way to avoid hack attacks is to use a server other than Google Play Services to protect your game.

Server side verification can be used to eliminate some fraud, but probably not all of them. Specifically, games that use server-side verification do not protect the local storage of the game’s system files from getting hacked.

Comment: I have already a separate server for verification but there's only one case that I mentioned. I could fix it by using some logic but just wondering what is the proper way to tackle that kinda issues.